# Permissions revoke delay

Tags: sharepoint-server, claims-based-auth

I have a strange issue with permissions. We have a web application with custom claims provider (I do not know if this is connected with the issue). We have some site collections with many documents (all documents have broken permissions... I know it is not ok but it has to be that way). The issue is that when I assign a user to a group (this group exists 'inside' our custom claims provider) the user receives permissions immediately - he can open the document. But if I revoke permissions - user still can open the document for around 4 or 5 minutes. After that time the permissions are 'truly' revoked. What the...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that this has to do with the Token refresh time.  Basically the user's token is pulled from cache until X minutes have passed and the token is refreshed, thus picking up the revocation of permissions.

This might get you on the right track.

https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/07/06/sharepoint-2013-use-ag-groups-yes-butdont-forget-the-security-token-caching-logontokencacheexpirationwindow-and-windowstokenlifetime/

Comment: I do not understand those settings. And I suppose no one does. I had set this to 10 HOURS(!) and 10 minutes. But still I had to wait 4-5 minutes (why?) I set this to 10 minutes and 2 minutes respectively and now permissions are revoked immediately. Why not after few minutes? Additionally, I have a local VM with the same settings (10 hours and 10 minutes) and I do not have this issue at all...